# Memory Leak in UIWebview on loading NSURLRequest

Tags: iphone, ios, uiwebview, memory-leaks

I have created a custom browser for my app. Whenever i load a url request into web view a memory leak is seen. Please note that no backtrace is shown. Application has a webview  and a refresh button is given below it.

The code on refresh button is as follows

```
   - (IBAction)refresh:(id)sender
{
// Some solution suggested by online community but in vain
    [wvWebView loadHTMLString:@"" baseURL:nil];
    [wvWebView stopLoading];
    wvWebView.delegate = nil;

// Clearing cache Memory
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:0 forKey:@"WebKitCacheModelPreferenceKey"];
    [[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeAllCachedResponses];
    [[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] setDiskCapacity:0];
    [[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] setMemoryCapacity:0];

// Deleting all the cookies
    for(NSHTTPCookie *cookie in [[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] cookies])
    {     
            [[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] deleteCookie:cookie];
    }

// Loading webview with desired url
    [wvWebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"]]];
}
```

Please help me to solve this issue as early as possible

Comment: Is this in the simulator or on a real device? If it's the simulator, please test again on a real device, the simulator uses a different memory model and will sometimes report leaks that aren't there! (FYI there's no obvious leak in your code!)

Comment: What does the static analyser say?

Comment: I had tested the above code on real device and not on simulator

Comment: @Will static Analyzer doesnot show any issues